# python insert Analytics code into all files

Tags: python, google-analytics

I am trying to insert a google analytics script into all of my HTML pages, but the content of the files are duplicated when i run the script again.

Why is my script duplicating the file contents and appending it to the end of the file?

How can I add the analytics script to all files that do not have it?

```
import fnmatch
import os

track_code = """
    <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-48664735-1', 'kylelk.github.io');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>
    """


matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.html'):
        matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

for file_name in matches:
    try:
        html_file=open(file_name, "r+")
        html_data = html_file.read()
        if "</head>" in html_data and not "UA-48664735-1" in html_data:
            print file_name
            html_data1=list(html_data)
            #find index of closing "head" tag
            html_data1.insert(html_data.find("</head>"), track_code)
            html_file.write("".join(html_data1))
            html_file.close()

        elif "</HEAD>" in html_data and not "UA-48664735-1" in html_data:
            print file_name
            html_data1=list(html_data)
            html_data 1.insert(html_data.find("</HEAD>"), track_code)
            html_file.write("".join(html_data1))
            html_file.close()
    except IOError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what you're doing here is:
1. opening the file in read/write mode
2. read the whole file contents, which positions the internal file pointer at the end of the file
3. rewrite the whole contents (with added script) at the current file pointer's position - that is, at the end of the file.

What you *want* to do is replace the file's content. The simplest and safest solution is to:

1. open the file in read only
2. read it and close it
3. add your script to the content
4. reopen the file in write mode and write your new content.

Now since your updated content is going to be longer than the original one, you could also just reposition the internal file pointer (using `file.seek(0)` before writing.